# How to unescape JSON output?

Tags: jquery, json

My server should be returning a URL string to pass into my Success method of an Ajax call. All I want to do is use this URL to perform a simple redirect, but the string coming back from the server looks strange.

Here is whats coming back from the server:

```
"products\/1\/volvo-xc90-t6"
```

The code that returns this from the server is this:

```
<cfreturn "products/#rsProduct.ProductID#/#rsProduct.ProductTitle#" />
```

So I'm getting everything including the double-quotes and the escaped slashes. The redirect fails using this string when I include it part of this code:

```
success: function (result) {
        window.location.replace(result);
}
```

How do I get the string to format correctly? It is something on my server-side that needs to fix this or is it my JQuery thats wrong?

Comment: Your server side is trying to escape forward slashes by the looks of it. PHP?

Comment: Sorry its ColdFusion. I just added the tag but will get flamed for it I guess.

Comment: What does your AJAX call look like? If you are using jQuery, are you specifying that the return values are JSON? You should not need to use `replace()` on the JSON string in order to get the correct value.

Comment: Why don't your adjust your ColdFusion code to return something easier for your javascript to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the extra slashes on the front end, like this:

```
success: function (result) {
    window.location.replace(result.replace('\/', '/'));
}
```

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that `window.location.replace` will remove the previous page from history, therefore the user can not click the browser's back back to return to your previous page. To keep history, use `window.location.href = result.replace('\/', '/')`

Comment: You're welcome, please see the updated answer if you're looking to maintain the history too.

Comment: This may work, but it may be a way around something that is being done incorrectly and rather than doing it correctly, this kind of kludges it.

Comment: @ScottStroz, I agree that the issue is the way that the server side returns the URL however, I am not familiar with ColdFusion to suggest a solution there.

Comment: @junkystu My comment was more for the OP than you.

Comment: I would also be willing to bet that the problem is more with how he is handling the AJAX call than anything on the server side.